How can I emit data query from mongodb from flask to react
I have code segment to query data from mongodb using pymongo in flask as follow:
   pipline = [...]
   listCursor = list(collections.aggregate(pipeline))
   jsonData = dumps(listCursor, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')

   socketio.emit('add_news', jsonify(listCursor))

   return jsonData

I can return jsonData from flask backend to react frontend but I cannot emit it through socket, the result I get in socket is an array buffer. However, when I hardcode an array and emit it it still works correctly as follow .
How can I send my data as the hardcode I made?
